# How to get characters from emoji picker [ctrl-command-space]

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

on OS X the 'Emoji & Symbols' picker can be started from the menu or [ctrl-command-space] how do I get the characters from this in my view? (just an NSView with text handling in core text).

i.e. I double click on the emoji in the picker and how do I receive it in my view - I'd guess there's a delegate I have to set somewhere - but can't seem to find the docs - I'm probably not calling it the right thing when I google

I've made a basic app

and added the lines below to the view controller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.view)
        self.view.becomeFirstResponder()
```

and made a view MyNSView with and set the view in the storyboard to MyNSView

```
override public func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    interpretKeyEvents([event])
}
```

When I use the emoji picker, the keydown doesn't fire (I put a breakpoint on it). Maybe the emoji comes from another method?

Seems I have to implement NSTextInputClient - see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TextInputView/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have to implement NSTextInputClient - see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TextInputView/Introduction/Intro.html